# WCF Client configuration - redirect multiple services to another host

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client, endpoint, base-address

Right now, i have multiple services in my **client** web.config like this:

```
<endpoint address="http://hostname/ServiceA.svc"
         binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_MyBinding"
         contract="ServiceReference.ISearchService" name="ServiceA">
</endpoint>

<endpoint address="http://hostname/ServiceB.svc"
         binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_MyBinding"
         contract="ServiceReference.ISearchService" name="ServiceB">
</endpoint>
```

and quite some more

This web.config makes switching between hosting environments difficult and error-prone, because you need to replace the "hostname" on all and each one of the endpoint addresses.

I want to somehow add an environment app setting or something somewhere that will let me specify a host, and have the endpoint be resolved like `http://{hostA}/ServiceX.svc`

Do i need to do some magic programmatically or can i do this from configuration alone?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016285/wcf-client-configuration-base-address

Comment: @marc_s can you provide an example or a link? my services are declared in <system.serviceModel> <client> <endpoint ... > </> and all examples i've seen put the base address inside a <services> <host> tag

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about this being on the client side - base addresses work on the server side only, unfortunately :-(

Comment: a simple ctrl+h (find and replace) :p can do the donkey work for you if you do not need to change it while the app will be live.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do it via code - there's no "wildcard" in config which you can use for the base address in the `<system.serviceModel / client>` section. You can, however, have some placeholder in config (like "localhost") and in code first load the config, then update the server name with the actual value (which can be stored in config as well, e.g., in the AppSettings, or somewhere else).

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISearchService>("ServiceA");
factory.Endpoint.Address = ReplaceServerName(factory.Endpoint.Address);
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
...
```

Comment: +1 yeah, I guess this would be the only halfway manageable solution for the client side - too bad there's no "base address" concept on the client side...