# Handling ever changing baseAddress in WCF host

Tags: c#, wcf

As stated in the question, I need to handle a changing baseAddress property of a WCF service host. I have a simple object that contains a picture's binary value. This will be sent from a remote computer (actually a multitude of different ones) to the server through a Web app on the server that requests a specific file name based on given files in a database.

To do this I have made the service and implemented the necessary contracts, but I am stuck at the baseAddress element in the service's config file.

The dilemma is that the remote machine's IP is dynamic. It changes at about 5 min intervals (externally provided)  and the machine is not part of a VPN or any (inter)network and has no DNS configured. It only has its pc name set. I am however able to pull the IP of this device from a table to provide to the client app with the 'correct' IP to bind to, but my issue is rather at the host side.

The question is basically - in this described host, how do I specify the baseAddress that clients will bind to? I imagine I cannot rebind every time an IP address change is detected, or would that be no issue?

I have tried specifying "http://localhost:6090/BasicService/" which was unreachable when I attempted from the client to call "http://192.168.0.4:6090/BasicService/". However when I specify the exact IP in both client and host, the client successfully contacts the host.

Note that the binding of my service is basicHttpBinding and the private IP addresses are just in a test environment. When live, these devices receive their IP from m2m providers.

EDIT:
For better understanding, the remote device will be the server and contains the binding information which is XYZ and XYZ is what I am trying to figure out. The client can connect to a local machine to retrieve a specific remote device's IP and then bind the client to that given IP, but the issue is that in the host I am unsure as to what to use in the following:
    host
    baseAddresses
    add baseAddress="http://????????:6090/"
    baseAddresses
    host

The suggested answer below does help when these devices are in a closed network and you call the server's private IP, but does not work with the server's public IP.

Comment: You are using incorrect terminology.  _"base address"_ is from the perspective of the server only, **not** the client.  The client must always specify the full URL.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016285/wcf-client-configuration-base-address

Comment: If you are not going to use DNS then you might want to consider a fixed IP that is routed to the device on the dynamic IP.  The same principle is used with load balancers or hiding computers from the Internet

Comment: _"...when I specify the exact IP in ... client ..., the client successfully contacts the host"_ - well what did you expect?    If you run the client on the actual host _then_ you can use `localhost`.  However, clients running on a computer **different** to the host can **never** use `localhost`.  It seems you need an understanding of IP resolution

Comment: @MickyD I know how the IP address resolution works, the question is understood in reverse. Please see the comment I provided on the answer below. What I meant with this was that when I specify "localhoost" in the server, I thought that maybe that means that the service will host on the device's current IP.

Comment: Note that my answer _is_ the answer to your question. Your next question should be about IP resolution, not about server bindings.

Comment: @JessedeWit Yes you are right. I got this to work based on the config you provided as well as the port forwarding. I connected to a machine successfully using the methodology provided. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion about your question (see comments). In this answer I assumed your clients *do* know the IP address of your server, but your problem is binding the server to an unkown IP address.

### Server side

In order to listen to any ip address on your server side, you could use ip address 0.0.0.0. This way, on the server side, you don't need to worry about the ip address. Like so:

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://0.0.0.0:6090/BasicService" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

### Client side

And on the client side, you can make the binding dynamic, by specifying it in code:

```
string ipAddress = GetIpFromTable(); // Assuming client can do this...
string url = $"http://{ipAddress}:6090/BasicService";
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var address = new EndpointAddress(url);        
var client = new BasicServiceClient(binding, address);
```

You may run into some trouble when the ip address changes during/before a request though, so make sure you have your error handling in order and retry if the first attempt failed.

Comment: That won't work when _"...the remote machine's IP is dynamic. It changes at about 5 min intervals..."_.  The problem is that the client needs to know where the server is **not** what IP or base address to listen on

Comment: @MickyD I believe you're mistaken. What about the sentence _'I am however able to pull the IP of this device from a table to provide to the client app with the 'correct' IP to bind to, but my issue is rather at the host side.'_

Comment: Incorrect.  Just how is the server going to pass on this information when it has no idea where the client is?  Besides, the more important issue is the point I quoted

Comment: @MickyD The client knows where the server is by pulling the IP from a table. There is never a way for the server to know where the client is, unless the client makes a call to the server... He just wants to bind his service to an IP address on the server side, but can't hardcode the ip address because it is changing every five minutes.

Comment: You are reading it wrong.  Clients don't know where the server is let alone obtain it from some remote database.

Comment: @MickyD Well, let's have Joandre settle this difference in interpretation of the question.

Comment: It could well be the case.  It's clear he doesn't know what WCF _"base address"_ is so who knows what else is wrong with his terminology and/or grammar

Comment: @MickyD is correct. I see that the given answer helps on the client side not the server side. So yes the remote device is the one that will host the service and that pc's public IP changes the whole time. These IP addresses get pushed to a server (local machine that the client applications [other local machines] will be able to connect to to query the "correct host/wcf service host machine" IP to bind to at that given moment in time). So Host is remote with constant changing IP address, whereas client has the ability to pull the IP. I need to set the Host to handle these IP changes.

Comment: @JessedeWit Thank you this answer helps a lot, but this is a solution to the client's binding information rather than that of the host.

Comment: @JoandreTait I added the client side code just for clarity. The XML configuration is for your server side. You just want to listen to any ip address on the server side, right? Use ip address `0.0.0.0` in your bindings is what I'm saying.

Comment: @JessedeWit Hi, yes the remote pc changes IP the whole time so I want to specify 
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://0.0.0.0:6090/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
to handle the changing IP in the server/host. This failed when I called the public IP of a device. I placed that config exactly in the server config but when from the 'client' in a browser I typed the server's public IP and tried to connect to no avail. However when I type the Private IP of that device in the browser, it works.

Comment: Ah, that's a networking issue rather than a configuration issue. Perhaps [this](https://superuser.com/a/1112210), [this](https://superuser.com/a/987191) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/260014/access-internal-ip-using-public-ip) will help you. You still need the 0.0.0.0 ip address in your server bindings though.

Comment: @MickyD I believe I was sort-of right after all ;-)